# Enumerate Oracle tables in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do you run a query to list all tables, or all tables where tableName like '%abc%'.

Just poking around, I tried the following with no success:

```
select * from SYS.TAB$
select * from SYS.OBJ$ where Name like '%abc%'
```

I'm trying to re-learn in Oracle some basic things I know in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your privilege level, you'd want to use `DBA_TABLES`, `ALL_TABLES`, or `USER_TABLES`.  There is a [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle/205746#205746) that walks through this in some detail.

By default, Oracle identifiers are going to be stored in upper case in the data dictionary and queries are case-sensitive.  Most likely, if you have a table whose name contains the string "abc", you'd need to search in upper case, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_tables
 WHERE table_name LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Comment: Perfect, and I can filter on OWNER as well.